# Entity to model mapping in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have article and author classes.

Fetch articles like so and map entity to model:

```
public List<Model.Article> GetArticleList() {
    using (var db = new ArticlesContext()) {
        return db.Articles.Select(t => new Model.Article() {
            Author = MapUserEntityToModel(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == t.UserID))
            Title = t.Title,
            Teaser = t.Teaser
            // etc
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because LINQ can't run that function at run-time. What's the simplest and cleanest way to do the mapping?

Here are models:

```
namespace Model {
    public class Article {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Teaser { get; set; }
        public User Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }

    public class User {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here are entities:

```
namespace MyProj {
    public class Article {
        [Key]
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Teaser { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }

    public class User {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleContext : DbContext {
        public ArticleContext() : base("name=conn") {
            public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
            public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before continue, map your relationship in a navigation property:

```
public class Article {
    [Key]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Teaser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User Author {get; set; } // navigation property

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

And then just project your navigation property to his equivalent Model:

```
public List<Model.Article> GetArticleList() {
    using (var db = new ArticlesContext()) {
        return db.Articles.Select(t => new Model.Article() {
            Author = new Model.User {
                DisplayName = t.User.DisplayName,
                Email = t.User.Email,
                Website = t.User.Website,
                PasswordHash = t.User.PasswordHash
            },
            Title = t.Title,
            Teaser = t.Teaser
            // etc
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, just return `db.Articles` directly:

```
using Model;

public List<Article> GetArticleList() {

    using(var db = new ArticlesContext()) {
        return db.Articles.ToList();
    }
}
```

Assuming your EF model is set-up correctly with Foreign Keys, your `Article` type will have a lazily-evaluated `Author` property which will return a `User` object when accessed.